# Questions about differences between the same game on different platforms

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing, site-policies

Are questions that concern the differences between the same game between different platforms permitted or encouraged?

An example of this:

> [How many official versions of flappy birds are there?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162249/how-many-official-versions-of-flappy-birds-are-there)

I've noticed that this question has been closed as too broad, apart from potentially being too broad, is the fact that this question concerns cross platform differences a potential justification for closure? Are there any guidelines that people can look to when asking such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are questions that concern the differences between the same game between different platforms permitted or encouraged?

They should be permitted, I don't see what the problem is. In fact, there are already a lot of these sorts of questions on the site, many with positive votes. Here are some examples:

- [Differences in Fallout 3 between Xbox 360 and PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/differences-in-fallout-3-between-xbox-360-and-pc)
- [FIFA 13 cross-platform, any differences?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98004/fifa-13-cross-platform-any-differences)
- [Any difference between Alan Wake's PC and Xbox 360 versions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51329/any-difference-between-alan-wakes-pc-and-xbox-360-versions)
- [Is there a functional difference between the console and PC versions of the LEGO games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-the-console-and-pc-versions-of-the-lego)
- [What's the difference between the PC, 360 and PS3 versions of Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34420/whats-the-difference-between-the-pc-360-and-ps3-versions-of-skyrim)
- [What features differ between the XBLA and PC versions of minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65771/what-features-differ-between-the-xbla-and-pc-versions-of-minecraft)
- [What are the differences between The Sims 3: Pets on Windows and Xbox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94147/what-are-the-differences-between-the-sims-3-pets-on-windows-and-xbox-360)

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. It's *correct*, but as Billy's answer cogently points out, it's also kind of orthogonal to the actual reason the question in question was closed.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The closure of the flappy birds question is incidental to the meat and potatoes (most important thing) of this meta question. However, a link to [Billy Mailman's answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8547/61492) would certainly be an appropriate means to provide more information about the specific circumstances of the closed question. The answer marked as the accepted answer clearly and directly addresses the core meaning of the question at hand, it provides examples and is likely to be more useful to people who want to know about this.

Comment: @Alex Then you picked a really bad question to use as your example, as that closure has nothing to do with version differences whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Not only are questions about the differences between versions acceptable, we even have a tag for such questions, the aptly-named [version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences) tag!

That question about Flappy Bird isn't closed for being about version-related stuff. It's closed (or at least, I voted to close it) because it's essentially asking for a full list of the changes in every version and every update that was ever made to any official Flappy Bird release. That kind of question, looking for a really long list of every version ever, usually doesn't work well.

If he'd limited it to asking for just the platforms it had released on, it'd have probably been fine. But asking for a full changelog of every revision ever released for a game is just way too broad.

Comment: -1 Our policy is to fix questions which are salvageable, rather than closing them.  The *"it's asking for a full list of the changes in every version"* portion can be easily fixed by simply removing the words *"updates/revisions"*.

Comment: I don't think the OP of that question is interested in knowing the revision/update history of Flappy Bird, but rather, which "Flappy Bird"-type games are official. There are a lot of clones/remakes out there, which could make this confusing.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft One of the most important reasons we put questions on hold is to get the OP to edit them.

Comment: RE: your last paragraph: The original revision of the question wrote it as *"How many offical versions of flappy birds are there?"*, Which I interpreted as 'versions' being **platforms**, not 'revisions'. I highly doubt the OP wanted us to dive into a Readme file. It only became open-ended/asking about 'revisions' following the closure/argument, when the OP edited to take on other's suggestions.

Comment: @Rob Quoting from revision 1, emphasis mine: "Including original versions, Android, iOS and **updates/revisions**?" He was asking for a full changelog from the start, the edits removing it shouldn't have happened, as they changed the intent of the question, and it should never have been reopened.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The choice is either or.  There is *zero* requirement to editing instead of closing.  Just because you *can* edit does **not** mean you should.  I disagree *entirely* with your interpretation that editing should be done instead of closing.